# How can i assign ID to array of DIVs like "#page_pricing .col1 div div"

Tags: javascript, html

How can i assign ID to array of DIVs like "#page_pricing .col1 div div"

```
    <div id="page_pricing">
        <div class="col1">
            <div>
                <div id="###">
                  <h1>Express Portrait</h1>
                  <p>Need professional pictures, but don't have a lot of time? This session is for you</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why you cannot have `id="the_id_you_want"` on the element?

Comment: Something like `page_pricing_col1_##` where `##` is the array index?

Comment: If you'll be having a couple of divs inside a single page, you better you class. As HTML would not allow element with same id.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really work like that, there has to be a container object (think html element). So the best way to get the result you want is to wrap up the divs you want to be in an array inside a parent object, a parent div, or span would work. So then that container can be given an id and you can reference your array by the children property of the parent object.

```
<div id=parent>
  <div id=child0></div>
  <div id=child1></div>
  <div id=child2></div>
  <div id=child3></div>
</div>
```

You would reference the array of children as `document.getElementById('parent').children`